# Export results from Query Studio in excel file or SFTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-export

I am trying to export the results I get in Query Studio to Excel files without importing them into a data extension. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: the short answer is no; in order for any custom data set to be pulled from the system, you have to use data extract / file transfer activities in automation studio. Those are based on data extensions. (lists too, but those cannot be used in conjunction with SQL)

Comment: Also Query Studio is likely going away in 2022 Q4.

Answer (score 0):

In the results, there should be a "Export in Contact Builder" option on top of the columns that will link you to the temporary data extension, from which you can export.